# SonarQube console fails to start

Tags: ubuntu, sonarqube

On Ubuntu 16.04. I installed [SonarQube](https://sonarqube.org) 6.4. as follows:

1. Add `deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/deb binary/` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Run `sudo apt-get update` - this succeeds but [prompts a warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924693/the-repository-sonar-pkg-does-not-have-a-release-file).
3. Run `sudo apt-get install sonar`

Then I am trying to start *SonarQube* in the **console modus** but it immediately **stops**. I cannot see the reason for the start failure.

```
~ sudo /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh console
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2017.06.12 20:13:54 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] 
  Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
jvm 1    | 2017.06.12 20:13:54 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] 
  Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java 
  -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k 
  -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
  -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp 
  -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer 
  /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process8383619119685554365properties
jvm 1    | 2017.06.12 20:13:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] 
  Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2017.06.12 20:13:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] 
  SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I configured the user settings, embedded database, webserver settings and Java 8 in `/opt/sonar/conf/sonar.properties` resp. `/opt/sonar/conf/wrapper.conf`.

Here is the [output of the `/opt/sonar/logs/es.log`](https://pastebin.com/ng4qzSte)

---

## Related websites

- [Installation Jenkins and Sonarqube as CI on ubuntu/trusty64](https://gist.github.com/micheleorsi/bd20912b2489f3432558)
- [Installing SonarQube on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.voyalab.com/2016/10/06/install-sonarqube-ubuntu/)
- [How to Install SonarQube with Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-sonarqube-ubuntu-16-04-ngnix/)
- [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)

Comment: Check *$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/web.log*

Comment: There is no `web.log`. I found a `sonar.log` which contains the same output as I captured from the shell. Other files in the directory are `access.log` and `es.log`.

Comment: There should be. Make sure 1) there's space on the device 2) the user running SonarQube has perms to create and write to files in the logs dir.

Comment: I am starting _sonar_ via `sudo /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh console` to take a first look. I am not aiming at a permanent installation. The directories have permissions set for the `sonar` user. Do I need to run _sonar_ via that user? How can I do that? - There is enough space left on the disc.

Comment: I also tried to start _sonar_ via `service sonar start`. The shell output confirms the start process but I can see in `sonar.log` that it stops immediately like when I start it via the shell script.

Comment: Just to mention: the environment variable `SONARQUBE_HOME` is not set in my shell. If I understand correctly you posted it as an example. I used my custom path `/opt/sonar/` instead.

Comment: Yes @JDD, that was just a placeholder for "[your path here]"

Comment: Here is the content of my [`sonar.properties` file](https://pastebin.com/XTuZscw2).

Comment: Did you user a clean install? Stop SonarQube, delete the /data/es/ folder and restart.

Comment: Nice catch - thank you. Seems like I installed SonarQube before. It starts now and points me to upgrade the database. Any advice on that?

Comment: I tried with renaming `/opt/sonar/data/sonar.h2.db` but that did not solve the database upgrade issue. Finally, I uninstalled sonar, renamed `/opt/sonar` and installed sonar fresh. - Thank you for your help. - You might want to **improve the error messages** when a former installation blocks the startup. - Please extract your comment(s) as a full answer so I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your instance is not starting: check if you executed the following steps:

- Upgrade your plugins first, if needed.
- After download of the zip, **unblock** the zip before extracting.
- Always start with a new directory: *c:\Sonar\SonarQube-6.4* for example.
- Check the security rights on that folder if you want to run SonarQube as a service.
- Check your plugins, some may not be supported. Copy the supported add-ins to the new instance and start SonarQube using the default H2 database. Check the SonarQube log if the instance is not started. Then stop the instance, remove the files in the data, logs and temp folder and change the database connection.
- Make a **backup** of your database. There is no simple rescue path if things goes wrong.
- If creating a new database: be sure to use the **right collation**.
- Start SonarQube again and perform the setup action if migrating.